# iBUYPOWER CZ-17 touchpad won't scroll in Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, drivers, touchpad

I'm using a customized MSI build from iBUYPOWER. I think the base is in the G60 or G70 series. Info on the base model its PC Magazine review (I would post a link but I need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links), and I am using the touchpad that comes in all versions of this laptop. Some time after upgrading to Windows 10, I find that I cannot two finger scroll or two finger middle-click using the Elantech touchpad on my laptop. Furthermore, the "Options" button is grayed out in the ELAN properties menu, and it says "Standard PS/2 Mouse".  [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdEE3.jpg)

I try re-installing the touchpad Windows 8 driver (no win10 driver was posted) and the ability to scroll with the touchpad comes back on reboot, as expected. The Options button on the properties pane is no longer grayed out either, although clicking it doesn't appear to do anything. It looks like this: [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL8K3.jpg)

However, when I boot up again, I am unable to scroll with the touchpad again, and the Option button is once again grayed out.

In case it's relevant, there are three items listed in the Device Manager under "Mice and other pointing devices", and this isn't even with my USB mouse plugged in. There is "ELAN PS/2 Port Input Device" and two "HID-compliant mouse" entries. Here are the Hardware Ids for "ELAN PS/2 Port Input Device":

ACPI\VEN_PNP&DEV_0F03

ACPI\PNP0F03

*PNP0F03

The only change I've made to this laptop after buying it is to upgrade the wireless adapter to one that supports Wireless-ac

Comment: Your touchpad doesn't have Windows 10 compatible drivers that exist

Comment: Damn it ! Where did you find that out and is there any way to mitigate this issue?

Comment: Migrate back to Windows 8.1 I know of no Elan device drivers that support Windows 10